# Underline of <a> link doesn't go a way

Tags: html, css

I want the words of my link to be red and the underline to show up only when it's hovered, and this is my code:

```css
a:hover div {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a div{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div>next page</div>
</a>
```

Now the color of the text is red but the underline doesn't disappear. Why?

Comment: How can an inline element `a` contain a block element `div`

Comment: @MarkPerera In HTML5 you can have a block element inside an inline element.

Comment: Just read about it. But only works with `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underline is not due to a style in the div. It's the default style for the a tag. Remove the div part in your css selector:

```css
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
    <div>next page</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just set `text-decoration:none` for `a tag`.

```
a{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

a:hover div {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

```css
a:hover div {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
a{
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
 <a href="">
        <div>next page</div>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a block level item (`div`) inside an inline item (`a`). So the browser that doesn't support it yet, might throw the `div` out of the `a`. Instead, use a `span` and give the `display: block` to it, while having `a` in either `block` or `inline-block`.

But for the browsers that support this behaviour, your solution will be this below snippet:

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover div {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div>next page</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation for why this would work please?

Comment: @Gropai You cannot have a block level item (`div`) inside an inline item (`a`). So the browser that doesn't support it yet, might throw the `div` out of the `a`. Instead, use a `span` and give the `display: block` to it, while having `a` in either `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar the web has moved on, you can put pretty much whatever you like in an anchor tag ;)

Comment: @Pete You think I am not aware of it? I am aware of it and saddened too. People gonna start using `h1` for bold items and `a` for underlined items soon! `:(`

Comment: If you are aware of it, you make a pretty big point of saying the opposite in both your answers and your comments

Comment: @Pete Yes, I am against it, it is against the semantics. `:)`